# Android: Setting width of View in inches (converting between inches and dp)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm making a ruler app and I want one of my views to be exactly 1.7 inches in width on any screen, regardless of the dpi of the individual device using the app. I know how to convert between pixels and dp and how to programmatically set the layout parameters of a view, but i'm not sure how to determine how many dp will be needed at each screen density to ensure my view is always drawn with a width of 1.7 inches.

Unless i'm mistaken, once I understand this conversion, I should be able to set this using a call like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( **width in dp converted from inches**, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
    public int pixelsOfWantedInches(double inches, Activity act) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int dens=dm.densityDpi;
        int pixels = (int)(inches * (double) dens);

        return pixels;
    }


int wantedPixels = pixelsOfWantedInches(1.7, this);
```